# Parameter Names in WSDL with significant name

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

I am creating a WebService in Java using JAXWS RI. 
The WSDL file is created when deploying the application WAR automatically. 
The problem is that I want the arguments (that each operation recieves) in the WSDL file to have significant names, but they appear as arg0, arg1, arg2 ...
Is there a way to define the names for this parameters and don't use the default names?

I have implemented the following:

***The WebService Interface***

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface WS2 {
    @WebMethod String confirmaXML(String lrt_id);
}
```

***The WebService Interface Implementation***

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "vital.tde.ws2.WS2")
public class WS2Imp implements WS2{
    public String confirmaXML(String lrt_id) {
        String respuesta = null;
        //CODE
        return respuesta;
    }
```

***sun-jaxws.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime"
    version="2.0">
    <endpoint name="WS2" implementation="vital.tde.ws2.WS2Imp" url-pattern="/WS2" />
</endpoints>
```

***web.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>WS2</display-name>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
                com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
        </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>WS2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WS2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WS2</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: You're automatically generating the WSDL from your web-service class?

Comment: @Mac Yes, I edited my question to indicate based upon what the WSDL is generated

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you're generating your WSDL from your web service class, you may add [`WebParam`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/jws/WebParam.html) annotations to the parameters of your methods to enforce naming in the WSDL. For example:

```
@WebService
public class FooService
{
    @WebMethod(operationName = "barMethod")
    public void bar (@WebParam(name = "bazArg") int baz)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The above snippet configures JAX-WS to use the name "bazArg" for the method's parameter name in the WSDL.

Comment: Fantastic! Glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: This might have changes with the new CXF connector, now these annotations must be added to the interface.